# Using getElementById inside user control

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a usercontrol that hides a div when a button is clicked.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" OnClientClick="ShowHide(); return false;" runat="server" />  
<div id="popupPage" style="display:none;">
</div>


 function ShowHideGotoPopUp() {
        var ob = document.getElementById("popupPage");
        if (ob.style.display == "none")
            ob.style.display = "block";
        else ob.style.display = "none"

    }
```

There is a problem when I place on page more then 1 usercontrol, all controls has div with same id = popupPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rethink how this works; the ID should be unique for a HTML page.

If however, you want to stick with your current design, something like this should work...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" OnClientClick="ShowHide(this.nextSibling); return false;" runat="server" />  
<div id="popupPage" style="display:none;">
</div>
 function ShowHideGotoPopUp(ob) {
        if (ob.style.display == "none")
            ob.style.display = "block";
        else ob.style.display = "none"

    }
```

Comment: How can I set a unique id to the divs if it's inside a control and user can put on his page n*controls?

Comment: The control needs to generate a unique ID each time it's rendered. This ought to be pretty easy. Then your function can either take the ID as an argument (good idea) or the function can include the uniqueID as part of its name so the functions don't overwrite eachother.

Comment: Bialecki, can you please show how I can generate unique ID to the control and to divs inside it

Answer (score 0):

Since your control appears more than once on the same page you will have to generate a unique ID for your div for each instance of your usercontrol, then as Matt suggested change your function to take the div ID as a parameter.

Consider running your div as a server control( unique ID will be generated automatically). You can then access the unique client ID at the Load Event of your user control and pass it on to your function programatically(by setting the 'OnClientClick' attribute for your linkbutton) . ie..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//get the unique generated ID     
string divID = yourDiv.ClientID;

//pass it on to your function by setting OnClientClick

yourLinkButton.OnClientClick = "ShowHideGotoPopUp('" + divID + ')";

}
```

Comment: The div's ID is NOT generated automatically, all of them get the same id for every instance of user control.

Comment: Im not sure I understand you. If you run your div as a server control a unique Id will be generated automatically by ASpnet. But you can still set it at page load like this --> yourDiv.Attributes["id"] = divid;